# Scoping out maven plugin execution depending on environments

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using the ready-api-maven plugin for executing simple SOAP requests on my codebase which is deployed to a local JBoss server before the execution of the tests.

I am trying to figure out how to "scope out" the steps to deploy to a local JBoss server and run these tests when the build is executing on Jenkins. These tests are meant only for executing on a local system.

I'm quite new to maven and would really appreciate the help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can define it by using profiles. ex. you can specify two profiles: local and ci, in local profile you can specify to run the tests but in ci you can skip them.